# How to use Views to make a Block that displays a field from the author's profile?

Tags: views

using Drupal 7.

I have added a field in the user account settings called "author summary" (field_author_summary)

When a user is editing their profile, they can enter a brief description of themselves into this field.

Now, the goal is to display this information as a block, directly under the content they are the author of.

I can't figure out the proper contextual filters and/or relationships.

Any ideas?

Thanks!\

Comment: Just to clarify, I want to pull a field from a profile (the author of the current node) and display it in a block.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you have create a block view. (In case if you want to know how to create, check the revisions of this answer)

**Add Author Relationship**

[image]

**Add Fitter Criteria** : User: Current with *author* relationship
[image]

select **Is the logged in User** - yes. Click on Apply.

It pulls a field from a node (the author of the current node) and display it in a block

Comment: Krishna, thank you for your reply, very detailed. However, I want to display a field from the node author's profile, not the current user.

Comment: @Jason I've updated my answer hope it helps. If I missed anything from your question. let me know.

Comment: Thanks @Krishna Mohan. For some reason, it still won't work. That Filter seems to be messing it up. When I click "Yes" for "Is the logged in user", the block doesn't show up... When I click "No" (Is NOT the logged in user), the same profile field shows up for all content, regardless of node author.                                                       Gosh, I wish it weren't so complicated. All I would like to do is to display a little biographical information for each node's author, regardless of current user or if they're logged in or not.